# Matrix elements from commutation relations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, representation-theory, lie-algebra, linear-algebra

Suppose we are given commutators of the spin operators: $[S_X, S_Y], [S_Y, S_Z]$ and $[S_Z, S_X]$. Then can we completely determine the matrix representation of the operators? Can we do it in any dimension?

Comment: Almost always, yes! This is the whole study of representation theory. Depending on the algebra/group, some dimensions for representations may not exist, but that is something that can only be studied on a case by case basis.

Comment: @Prahar How do we find those matrices? I tried by using $2 \times 2$ matrix. Could not get anything good.

Comment: Well, you need to study representation theory. There is a whole field of study which deals with the construction of such matrices. The answer by @yyy is a reasonable place to start. You haven't really said in your question what the commutators actually are though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes (for each value of $S^2$ separately):

i) construct $S^{\pm} = (S_X \pm i S_Y)$ and get that they act as raising/lowering operators on $S_Z$ (by noticing that these are eigenoperatos of $S_Z$)

ii) construct $S^2 = S_X^2+S_Y^2+S_Z^2$ and see that it commutes with all of these operators, and deduce that it can be diagonalized together with $S_Z$, for example. Now, we can restrict ourselves each time to a certain subspace characterized by a specific eigenvalue of $S^2$. Note that it can be written as $S^2 = S_Z^2 + S^{+}S^{-} - \hbar S_Z = S_Z^2 + S^{-}S^{+} + \hbar S_z = S_Z^2 + S^{-}S^{+}-\hbar S_z$. Use this to get the normalization factors of the raising and lowering operators (hint: as this is fixed, we can look at it for a general eigenstate of $S_Z$)

iii) using the fact that $|| S^{\pm} |\psi\rangle ||^2 = \langle \psi | S^{\mp}S^{\pm}|\psi\rangle$, and the relations between $S^2$ and $S^{\pm}, S_Z$, get that the  relation between the normalization factors for the raising and lowering operators and the eigenvalues of $S^2$ and $S_Z$

iv) deduce that the eigenspectrum of $S_Z$ is bounded from below and above by the eigenvalue of $S^2$ (just from the fact that $\langle S^2\rangle \geq \langle S^2_Z \rangle$ due to it being sum of squares of hermitian operators), and combining that with the raising/lowering relations deduce that you can get all the eigenspectrum from starting at a maximal/minimal level and operating with lowering or raising until the state becomes null (similar to the harmonic oscillator)

v) combine all these to get that the spectrum is separated by integer values of $\hbar$, and that the stopping condition (which you will get from the raising/lowering normalization relation) restricts the eigenvalues to be of either integer of half-integer multiples of $\hbar$. From this get the matrix elements of the raising and lowering operators, and from them the matrix elements of $S_X$ and $S_Y$